# how to add separate digits of an integer?

Tags: python

The user should input a number and the program has to sum all the digits of the number up excluding the last digit.

For example:

> input: 12345
>
> n = 1+2+3+4 = 10

I currently have the following code:

```py
n = int(input())
n = n // 10
di = [int(d) for d in str(n)]
print(dig)
```

Above code outputs for input "123":

> [1, 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more step, that's all.

```py
n = int(input())
n = n // 10
di = sum([int(d) for d in str(n)])
print(di)
```

Output for 123:

```py
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, my answer can help you

```py
number = "12345"
convt2arr =  list(number)
result = 0
for x in convt2arr:
   if int(x) < len(convt2arr):
      result += int(x)
    
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
data = '12345'
_sum = sum(int(x) for x in data[:-1])
print(_sum)
```

output

```
10
```